# Sending touch event to a USB connected iPhone device using COCOA/MAC App

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

I have a requirement that, I need to test a iOS app from remote machine. Flow is follows :

Connect iPhone/iPad to any Mac OS system.
Create a Mac OSX application which can read my USB connected iOS device and show its screen when run the OSX application (Like mirroring).
Select any iOS app installed in USB connected iOS device and interact with that using OSX application.
Can someone please help me , is it possible with Mac OSX ioKit framework ?